# create DataTable with Two dimensional with InputText into cells

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I need create an primefaces Datatable with InputText into cells and get de information edited in the inputText

I create the datatable with the next code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{busquedaArticulo.attr}" var="rowName" styleClass="table table-bordered table-stripped" rowIndexVar="rowIdx">
<p:column headerText="" styleClass="ui-widget-header">
<h:outputText value="#{rowName}"/>
</p:column>
<p:columns value="#{busquedaArticulo.siz}" var="columnName" headerText="#{columnName}" columnIndexVar="colIdx">
<h:inputText id="siz" value="#" styleClass="form-control" />        
</p:columns>                                    
</p:dataTable>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use editable row. you can show value of each entry if it has been set by user or has a default value or leave it empty or "not set" if it's not set.
user can click on pencil icon and edit value of each row. once row has been edited you can get new value in your backing bean. 
look at this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml
hope it was useful :)